# How to update Bootstrap in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, npm, bootstrap-4, upgrade

I am developing a web application using Angular 6 and Bootstrap 4. I have installed bootstrap using npm install. (Not using CDN URLs) My problem is, how do I upgrade Bootstrap 4 in the future if I install bootstrap in this method? Should I un-install it and re-install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example package.json file.

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "~4.1.3"
  }
}
```

4.1.3 which means major.minor.patch

> if you see ~1.0.2 it means to install version 1.0.2 or the latest
>   patch version such as 1.0.4. If you see ^1.0.2 it means to install
>   version 1.0.2 or the latest minor or patch version such as 1.1.0

Reference:https://michaelsoolee.com/npm-package-tilde-caret/